# How to read cell data of excel file using openxml

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, openxml

I am reading the .xlsx file using DocumentFormat.openxml nuget pkg. I am trying to read the date cell[G2] and data from [b5] to [m5]

[image: Sample excel screenshot is attached]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sFileTypeError = string.Empty;
            string myFilePath = @"C:\Landing\file.xlsx";
            //string ext = Path.GetExtension(myFilePath);

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(myFilePath);
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            if ((fileExtension != ".xlsx") && (fileExtension != ".xls"))
                sFileTypeError = "Invalid file. \n\nPlease browse a correct Excel file to upload.";
            else
            {

                using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(myFilePath, false))
                {
                    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.First().Id.Value);
                    IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();

                }

            }
        }

 Please let me know how can read this. Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

I you want to go row by row and then cell by cell you can do this :

```
foreach (Row actualRow in rows)
{
    IEnumerable<Cell> cells = actualRow.Descendants<Cell>();
    foreach (Cell actualCell in cells)
    {
         // It gets the good value if it's not in the shared string table
         string value = actualCell.CellValue.Text;
    }
}
```